# Where to put the Exosuit Docking Station?

Tags: oxygen-not-included

What are exactly the requirements for the Exosuit Dockingstation?
*(Besides the obviously need for oxygen to pump up the Exosuits)*

Whenever I try to position a Dockingstation, my dupes refuse to use it. They use another way to the target or the Dockingstation blocks the way completely.

Do I have to put it in a specialized pressure chamber? Or has the environment temperature to be at a specific level?

How can I force my dupes to use a Exosuit before entering the hot oil biome for example?

Comment: Shame on me: It seems that it was only the missing Exosuit Forge (which allows the production of Atmo Suits). Without this, the Dockingstation is obviously useless. So you need all 3 parts to get your Dupes using this Suits.

Answer (score 1):

An Exosuit docking station needs to be placed next to an Exosuit checkpoint for duplicants to use it. I don't quite know the specifics, but I'm assuming you can set which directions to put on/take off Exosuits